# Android: No Animation is played (several buttons implementing the same animation effect)

Tags: android, animation, view, onclicklistener

I would like to apply the same alphaanimation for button A, B and C, and therefore implemented the following codes:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    animation = new MutableAlphaAnimation();
    animation.setAnimationListener(this);   

    btn_A.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {         
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {                           
            animation.setResetBlocked(true);
            btn_A.setAnimation(animation);
            animation.setResetBlocked(false);
            animation.start(0.0f, 0.5f, FADE_IN_DURATION);
            btn_A.invalidate();
        }  
    }); 
}

public class MutableAlphaAnimation extends Animation 
    {
        private float mFromAlpha;
        private float mToAlpha;
        private boolean resetBlocked;

        public MutableAlphaAnimation() 
        {
        }

        public void start(float fromAlpha, float toAlpha, long duration) 
        {
            mFromAlpha = fromAlpha;
            mToAlpha = toAlpha;
            setDuration(duration);
            setStartTime(START_ON_FIRST_FRAME);
        }

        public void setResetBlocked(boolean resetBlocked) 
        {
            this.resetBlocked = resetBlocked;
        }

        @Override
        public void reset() 
        {
            if (! resetBlocked) super.reset();
        }

        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) 
        {
            final float alpha = mFromAlpha;
            t.setAlpha(alpha + ((mToAlpha - alpha) * interpolatedTime));
        }

        @Override
        public boolean willChangeTransformationMatrix() 
        {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean willChangeBounds() 
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

### Question:

btn_A, B and C are implemented with the same `setOnClickListener`. However, when they are pressed, nothing happen. Why? How can the above be modified?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You aren't applying your transformation to btn_home. Yes you set the it to the animation, but your animation class never touches btn_home. Your t.setAlpha... should really be btn_home.setAlpha..., so pass in the view using the constructor and then you can use it with any view in the future.

Comment: can u elaborate more on how to code in the `OnCreate` or somewhere else so that once the btn_A is pressed it can show the animation? thank!!

Comment: Ok, had a chance to try out with actual code. That is not your issue. Issue is you are never starting the animation. Fix: add 'btn_A.startAnimation(animation);' in your onClick method as the last line. You can delete the btn_A.invalidate(); line, it isn't needed.